# cant break the loop in my socket properly

Tags: python, loops

I've created a socket with a login system. The code below is my login class on my client system. it receives the message login successful or username/password incorrect. the print statement shows that this is getting through fine from the server so my issue isn't there or on the server part. when a password is wrong it starts back to login which is what I want it to do.the issue is when it's a correct login. the server will send login successfully and that will print but it won't break out of the loop and will just continue to ask for my username and password.

```
def login():
username = str(input("Please enter your username to login: "))
password = str(input("Please enter your password to login: "))
joint =(username+password)
message = hashPW(joint)
s.send(message.encode())
ls = s.recv(1024)
print(ls)
while ls != "Login successfull":
    login()
else:
    after_choice()
```

server code: I don't think this is where the problem lies. I'm pretty sure it's with the client and me being unable to break it out of the loop properly or something but I figured id add it anyway to help.

```
def recive():
    password = c.recv(1024).decode()#reciving the password
    print("Password from client: ", password)
    PWcheck()

def PWcheck():
    f= open("passwords.txt")
    f1=f.readlines()
    if password in f1:
        print("Login successfull")
        ls =("Login successfull")
        c.send(ls.encode())
        wait() #just the next class
    else:
        print("Username or password incorrect")
        ls =("Username or password incorrect")
        c.send(ls.encode())
        recive()
```

if anyone needs more code adding i can. any  help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `login` call in the loop will not change the value of `ls` in the calling function.  You should instead move the code you wish to repeat into the body of the loop, and have no recursive calls to `login`.

Comment: @Patrik Haugh. thanks for the answer. ill give it a try. it sounds correct. ill get back to you in a moment.

Comment: Off topic, why is `password` a global in your server code?

Comment: @donkopotamus it was from when I was playing around with my code trying to get things to work. I tried moving the loop outside the class to see if I could use break to stop it when I wanted it too. quickly realised that didn't work. I must have forgotten to remove it. thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh so I edited my code. it's neater so thank you. my issue is still around, however. In my mind, this should work. if the password is wrong it says so. it's its right it says so. it just won't move on when the passwords right. so frustrating. Thank you for your help :D